# Javascript array insertion

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array in javascript which looks like this:

```
var arr = [
    { // first
        id : '45'
        name : 'dsada'  
    },
    {
        id : '45'
        name : 'dsada'
    },
    /* ... */
];
```

I want to add more data to the first index of it, e.g. `country:'Egypt'`.

Which function should I use?

Or how to push values to specific index in array?

I have used `push` and `splice` methods but I can't figure it out.

Comment: I think you may confuse JavaScript object literal (`{'thing':'value'}`) with JavaScript array (`['value','value','value']`). In PHP there are associative arrays and many people confuse them with object literals in JavaScript but in JavaScript there is no such thing as an associative array; only number indexed arrays. So an object literal does not have push, splice, pop and other array methods. In other words if you try `arr[0].push({country:'USA'})` it won't work because the object literal at arr[0] does not have a push method.

Comment: post.comments = {user: 'Yousra' , comment: 'hey'},{user: 'ahmed' , comment: 'okay'};
i cant insert that array into another array as comments !!?

Comment: You can but that's the first time any of us see post.comments and the first time you mentioned it. I guessed you tried push or splice because you confused an object literal with an array as that is a common mistake with php programmers

Answer (score 2):

```
arr[0].country = 'Egypt'
```

Set the `country` property.

Comment: Thank you !
So what if i want to make it an array
coountry : {
1 : 'egypt',
2 : 'america'
}

Comment: Then you would set it to `['Egypt','America']`, as an array.

Answer (score 0):

Scimonster's answer is correct, but it is better if you take a look to the documentation. Your question highlight some confusion on basics.

**Documentation**

The [Array.prototype.push()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) method adds one or more elements to the end of an array and returns the new length of the array.

The [Array.prototype.splice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) method changes the content of an array, adding new elements while removing old elements.

The [Object.prototype](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/prototype) represents the Object prototype object.